# How to Change a Color of Clusters in Google Map

Tags: javascript

How can I change the color of Clusters in google map from Blue(default) to Red. I tried so many times to code by add third attribute where cluster is rendered but all in vain. Kindly have a look into code and advice.

```
 var options = {
                maxZoom: 15,
                styles: [{
                    url: 'https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/transparent.png',
                    width: 53,
                    height: 53,
                    textColor: '#fff',
                    color: "red",
                }]
            }

            const markerCluster = new markerClusterer.MarkerClusterer({
                map,
                markers,
                options
            });
            // new MarkerClusterer({ markers, map });

            setInterval(function() {
                if (!infowindow.getMap()) {
                    $('.marker_google_map').removeClass('selected');
                }
            }, 1000);
```